# ReactJs, Semantic UI , toggle button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello i wanted to make a toggle button menu

ie by clicking on the button the div would increase the height with some transition

but I can't imagine how to do this in react

```
function App() {
  const handleClick = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };
  return (
    <div
      className="Wrapper"
      style={{
        backgroundColor: "#000",
        height: "30px",
        width: "200px"
      }}
    >
      <Button
        style={{ padding: 0, height: "30px", width: "200px" }}
        circular
        icon="settings"
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
        Button
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

my codebox: https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-minsky-j9x6x

Comment: Do you have an idea of the menu you want to do? If so, care to share a screen so I can help you

Comment: @Jose Felix thanks bro, like this: https://prnt.sc/qg7dte

Comment: I first thought of creating a container and padding it with 0 padding and then clicking on it would increase the height of that container

Comment: I don't know if it's the best way to get to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a state variable to your function. You can now use [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html) for that.

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Button } from "semantic-ui-react";
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from 'react';


function App() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(0); // declare new state variable "open" with setter
  const handleClick = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setOpen(!open);
  };
  return (
    <div
      className="Wrapper"
      style={{
        backgroundColor: "#000",
        height: (open ? "400px" : "30px"), // make the div tall when "open"
        width: "200px",
        transition: "height 1s" // transition for 1 second
      }}
    >
      <Button
        style={{ padding: 0, height: "30px", width: "200px" }}
        circular
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
        Button
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```